# Размытие фона при отправке формы

Tags: javascript, html, css

При отправке формы должна появляться надпись "спасибо за заявку" на размытом фоне. Что не так?

```js
$("form.callback").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $(th).find('.success').addClass('active').css('display', 'flex').hide().fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(th).find('.success').removeClass('active').fadeOut();
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 2000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

```css
.about-right {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5% 0;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.about-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.85);
}
.about-right .callback {
  justify-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.about-right .formhead {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.about-right .button {
  background: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
.about-right .input {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.success {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 10;
}
.success span {
  margin: auto;
}
.success ~ * {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.success.active ~ * {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(9px);
}
```

```html
<div class="about-form grid">
        
  <div class="about-right grid">
<form class="callback">
  <div class="success">
    <span>Спасибо за заявку!</span>
  </div>
  <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
  <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="WoodStar">
  <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="xxxxxx@xxx.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Заявка с сайта WoodStar">
  <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

  <div class="formhead">Оставить заявку</div>
  <p>Оставте заявку и мы Вам перезвоним!</p>

  <input type="text" name="Имя" class='input' placeholder="Ваше имя..." required>
  <input type="text" name="Телефон" class='input' placeholder="Ваше телефон..." required>
  <button type="button" class="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Можно конкретно узнать до отправки? или уже после завершения `ajax` запроса.

Comment: после нажатия кнопки отправить

Comment: Во первых если после нажатия и до отправки надо код для попапа вставить в `beforeSend: function() { //code },` а не в `success`. И еще вы добавляете ՝active՝ класс и сразу же делаете `hide()` и по вашему как оно должно показываться ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, у Вас нет события "submit", потому что у кнопки неправильный тип - надо изменить type="button" на type="submit".

Во-вторых, вполне возможно, что у Вас что-то не то с аяксом. Я, например, меняю done на fail, и тогда всё работает (*ну, здесь-то понятно, почему fail - вопрос в том, работает ли аякс у Вас*):

```js
$("form.callback").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).fail(function() {
        $(th).find('.success').addClass('active').css('display', 'flex').hide().fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(th).find('.success').removeClass('active').fadeOut();
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 2000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

```css
.about-right {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5% 0;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.about-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.85);
}
.about-right .callback {
  justify-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.about-right .formhead {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.about-right .button {
  background: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
.about-right .input {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.success {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 10;
}
.success span {
  margin: auto;
}
.success ~ * {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.success.active ~ * {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(9px);
}
```

```html
<div class="about-form grid">
        
  <div class="about-right grid">
<form class="callback">
  <div class="success">
    <span>Спасибо за заявку!</span>
  </div>
  <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
  <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="WoodStar">
  <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="xxxxxx@xxx.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Заявка с сайта WoodStar">
  <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

  <div class="formhead">Оставить заявку</div>
  <p>Оставте заявку и мы Вам перезвоним!</p>

  <input type="text" name="Имя" class='input' placeholder="Ваше имя..." required>
  <input type="text" name="Телефон" class='input' placeholder="Ваше телефон..." required>
  <button type="submit" class="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```